# Control label in other page in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want ask about control label or link

i have label in home page
and I want change this label content from admin page

how to control and  change it?

Comment: What's the relationship between the pages? Is the "home" page a master page? Or are they unrelated (except for perhaps links)?

Answer (score 1):

you want a sort of content management system, try saving this label in some datasource (xml or database) and then use it where required.

Answer (score 1):

More details would be good. You want to be able to have an admin page where you have an input form that allows you to set content on the home page? If so, there are a few ways to do that. One way is to use a database to store the content, and then load from database on the home page. Another way is to store data in the HttpContext object, this however is not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to the display text from some sort of dynamic source, such as a database, xml file, flat file, etc. In the admin page, you write to that data source and load the text for the source from that source as well.